# How to count number of records of a field in internal table in select statment?

Tags: abap

I took a internal table of type ty_marc.
in this internal table i took 2 fields matnr and werks_d.
I want to count number of materials manufactured in the plant (marc-werks) based on the entry given by user.

I wrote the code as...

```
if so_matnr is not initial.
select matnr werks from marc 
into table it_marc
where matnr in so_matnr.
endif.

loop at it_marc into w_marc.
write :/ w_marc-matnr. ( how to count total number of material eg:- material number : 100-100 to 100-110).
       w_marc-werks.
endloop.
```

I want to count total number of material and display the count in another field of same internal table.
Note : there could be 10 material for material number 100-100, so i want the count as 10 in another field of same internal table and 100-110 could have n records and the count should be n in the field.

Answer (score 3):

There are two easy options.

If you don't actually care about the plant (werks), use the `group by` clause and the `count` function in your `select` statement. Something like:

```
select matnr, count(*)
from marc
where matnr in so_matnr
group by matnr
into table it_marc_count.
```

Structure it_marc_count would need to have an integer field in the second position (and matnr in the first obviously).

If you do need werks, the easiest is to sort it_marc by matnr then use the `at end` and `sum` constructs in the `loop at` loop (or something similar). The examples at the end of [Processing Table Entries in Loops](http://help.sap.com/SAPhelp_nw04/helpdata/en/fc/eb381a358411d1829f0000e829fbfe/content.htm) should get you started.

Comment: you left the `group by` part out of your code example

Comment: I might be missing something, but `count( [column] )` is not supported in Open SQL. In this particular case you can use count( * ).

Comment: Was also missing the group by apparently. Have no means to test this at this time...